# Reference request: Toric Varieties in reverse order

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups, toric-varieties

I am looking for a book/text which introduces toric varieties in reverse order. Instead of starting with lattices, cones, fans and convex geometry, it should start with a toric variety $X$ and define from it the lattices $N$ and $M$ of cocharacters and characters of its dense torus, talks about limits, orbits, etc. and finally constructs the fan associated to the toric variety $X$. I can not find any text which does that. It is okay if the text assumes some basic knowledge of algebraic groups and geometric invariant theory. Pls help.